# Can I cook sous vide on a desk?

Tags: sous-vide

So would it be possible with some insulation perhaps from home depot to use a sous vide cooker like cheffstep's Joule on a surface like a wooden office desk with a medium to small sized pot or even a round crock pot provided there's enough space during work? Or would this become an issue over time? Thanks.

Comment: I used a half size steam tray pan. About 10X12X8" and cheap. Built a little plywood box around it. Rubber feet, and about an inch clearance between tray bottom and bottom plywood supplies good insulation.Souse vide cooker stick fits in perfectly. The box stays cool to the touch. **Much** better than the plastic tanks they sell.

Comment: Put the whole thing in a syrofoam cooler (or any cooler, really), and you won't have to pump in as much energy to maintain it.  (you can also just use a cooler so long as it's water-tight).  Crock pots are fine on the desk as-is (they usually have rubber feet), although I like to put mine on a sheet pan to deal with any potential dripping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a problem at all.  Use a trivet, cutting board, or even a folded towel under your container.  If you are at Home Depot, you could also get one of those cork mats that go under a planter.  Really, anything will work.  You just want to protect the surface from any potential heat and/or water (occasional spillage) damage.

Comment: Ah yeah, that's a good idea, a cutting board or small chopping/butcher block should definitely work or something like that, thank you! I plan to do OMAD dieting, and as a web developer with a schedule and not much time, I want to get creative!

Comment: Kudos for your self-restraint. If I tried OMAD and had the sous vide setup on my desk, I would be dangerous to be around.

Comment: @cellsheet - do you plan to sous vide daily? if so what do you cook?

Comment: I do, around 1-2lb of meat, fish, and vegetables perhaps mainly. Enough to get a daily nutrition anyways. Everything else would be cooked otherwise (i.e. egg and fruits, unless pasture raised eggs can be cooked this way as well, which might be possible, at least with some type of egg I read somewhere. Could be wrong however. Didn't thoroughly research).